# Do I need to synchronize a call to the interrupt method?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

Consulting the JavaDocs and the source code of the `Thread.interrupt()` method in `Java SE 7` I found this:

```
public void interrupt() {
    if (this != Thread.currentThread())
        checkAccess();

    synchronized (blockerLock) {
        Interruptible b = blocker;
        if (b != null) {
            interrupt0();           // Just to set the interrupt flag
            b.interrupt(this);
            return;
        }
    }
    interrupt0(); //1, Outside of the synchronized block
}

//...

private native void interrupt0();
```

As can be seen, the native method invocation at `//1` is outside of the synchronized block. So, is it safe if don't put a call to the `interrupt()` method into a `synchronized` block?

```
Thread t;
//something else
t.interrupt(); //Not in a synchronized block
```

Will it be thread-safe? What if more than 1 thread will try to interrupt it simultaneously? How will the native method `interrupt0` behave then?

Comment: Good question, I'd expect `interrupt0()` to be idempotent and thread-safe but without seeing the actual native implementation it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @biziclop It's most likely that you're right. But the docs don't say anything about being thread-safe. Probably, I'll have to consult the implementation of the `interrupt0()`

Comment: You're right, the documentation doesn't say anything about this issue. But if `Thread.interrupt()` wasn't inherently thread-safe, everything would be hideously unstable as there's no guarantee that it will be called from a `synchronized` block, and even if it is, there's no guarantee that those blocks will synchronize on the same lock object.

Comment: Why would it need synchronization? And on which object?

Comment: @xehpuk Good question, as I've been already told, it would be strange if the method were not be thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, the `Thread` class has to deal with this internally. If there's a need for methods to be called inside a `synchronized` block, it's stated in the documentation, see e.g. `Object.wait()` ("The current thread must own this object's monitor.").

Comment: I'm pretty sure the synchronization is so you throw the exception in a threadsafe manner. Doesn't look like it cares when you set the threads interrupt flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say yes ... it is thread-safe.

Reasons:

1. If it was necessary for applications to call `interrupt()` in a `synchronized` block, then the the spec (the javadoc) would say so, and also say what object you needed to synchronize on to get thread-safety.  In fact, the javadoc says nothing about this.
2. If it was necessary for applications to call `interrupt()` in a `synchronized` block, then the Oracle Java Tutorial on Concurrency would mention it [on this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).  It doesn't.
3. If external synchronization on the `Thread` object was necessary to make the `interrupt()` call thread-safe, then it is hard to explain why the method is doing internal synchronization as well.  (They could / would have made the entire method synchronized if it was necessary.)

The above evidence is (IMO) convincing, though not absolute proof.  If you wanted proof that `interrupt()` is thread-safe, you would get it by a thorough analysis of the native code implementation for `interrupt0()`.  I haven't looked at the native code, but I would expect that `interrupt0` is internally thread-safe, and that that is sufficient to make the `interrupt` method thread-safe.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. Thank's much.

Comment: BTW, maybe you know where this method's implemented. I mean can I find it in the `src.zip` sources provided with the `JDK`, don't you know that?

Comment: You need to download the complete OpenJDK source code bundle to get the native code.  (I've never succeeded in using web-based source viewer for the mercurial source "forest" ...)

Comment: You mean that repo for JDK7 `http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7`? The newest commit dated 2011-06-07...

Comment: Yea.  Something like that.  There are instructions on how to download  the sources on the openjdk site, IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

@xehpuk's question deserves more attention:

> Why would it need synchronization? And on which object?

The whole point of synchronization---the only point---is to protect data from corruption.  We use synchronization when it is impossible for one thread to advance the state of the program without creating a temporary invalid state that other threads must not be allowed to see.

In that case, we synchronize the code block that creates the temporary, invalid state, and we must also synchronize every code block that ever *looks at* the state.

So, when we talk about interrupting a thread, what *states* are we talking about?

Well, without looking at the code, it *seems like* there would be only two:  *Not-interrupted* and *interrupted*, and both of them are valid.  There's no obvious invalid state to go through to get from one to the other:  To get from not-interrupted to interrupted *seems like* one atomic operation.  So, a reasonable programmer would *expect* that there's no need for synchronization.

Of course, there might be some internal details that I have skipped over, but internal details should be hidden from the programmer.  A reasonable programmer would expect that, if there *is* a need for synchronization, then it either would taken care of inside the `interrupt()` method, or else it would be very clearly documented as the caller's responsibility.

Comment: I don't follow... are you talking about the thread that's being interrupted? I think the question is about the calling thread, where the interrupt method is called.

Comment: @GOTO0 james is talking about both. One perform a write (the thread invoking `interrupt()`) and one performs a read (the running thread that checks for interrupts). james is saying that neither one can ever write an invalid state for another to read; he bases that claim on the fact that there's no documentation about such a state or the responsibility of the call to `synchronize` to prevent it. +1, btw

Comment: @jpmc26 I see, thanks. Was misreading the part about the invalid state. +1 from me, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, source says interrupting a dead thread has no effect. So it'll be threadsafe inherently.

It says "Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect."

> Interrupts this thread. Unless the current thread is interrupting
>   itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess() methodof this
>   thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException to be thrown.
>   If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or  wait(long,int) methods of the Object class, or of the  join(), 
>   join(long), join(long,int),  sleep(long), or  sleep(long,int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an  InterruptedException. If this thread is blocked in an I/O
>   operation upon an java.nio.channels.InterruptibleChannel
>   interruptiblechannel then the channel will be closed, the thread's
>   interruptstatus will be set, and the thread will receive a
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException. If this thread is
>   blocked in a  java.nio.channels.Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   java.nio.channels.Selector wakeup method were invoked. If none of the
>   previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be
>   set. Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

Comment: AFAIK that's what the `blocker` field is responsible for. If that is set to a non-null value, `interrupt0()` is synchronized internally.